# Match font for an icon

Tags: fonts, icon, font-recommendation

Hi I am working with bootstrap navbar and I have 4 flat icons (very sharp outline) like below :

[image]

I need to make another one to show another menu option in the navbar. The new icon is only text with following text 'CCRT'. All icons are 64px X 64px in size.

I just want to know what font I can use that will look the icons (sharp and skinny)?

Comment: That's too broad... there are many skinny fonts.

Comment: Actually, finding a font with exactly 1 or 2 px stroke width at a specific size will be challenging. The best solution might be to draw the characters yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the font is the most important, any sans serif fits. The most relevant in terms of design is the shape: excepting the exit icon, they are all a circumference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this one: [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat)

Google fonts is a great tool to find the font you are looking for. You can choose the font and test it by writing your text and see the effect in all styles of the font.

Comment: `Proxima Nova Light` would be also a great choice

Answer (score 1):

Although a very broad question, since you already have an icon with text I'd choose the same font from the "24" in the 4th icon from the left. I don't want to suggest any specific font because there are many that would match.